# Does GeoServer work with Java 17? Tomcat 9 fails to start using Java 11

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

Exactly what versions of everything work with GeoServer? I still can't get any of it to work. Is there no guide that explains it for a newbie, including getting SSL working? I know it's all googleable but something always breaks when I follow some guide.

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is a very easy to find [manual page](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html) that explains this (and is kept up to date)

> GeoServer’s speed depends a lot on the chosen Java Runtime Environment
> (JRE). The latest versions of GeoServer are tested with both Oracle
> JRE and OpenJDK. Implementations other than those tested may work
> correctly, but are generally not recommended.
>
> Tested:
>
> ```
> Java 17 - GeoServer 2.22.x and above (OpenJDK tested)
>
> Java 11 - GeoServer 2.15.x and above (OpenJDK tested)
>
> Java 8 - GeoServer 2.9.x to GeoServer 2.21.x (OpenJDK and Oracle JRE tested)
>
> Java 7 - GeoServer 2.6.x to GeoServer 2.8.x (OpenJDK and Oracle JRE tested)
>
> Java 6 - GeoServer 2.3.x to GeoServer 2.5.x (Oracle JRE tested)
>
> Java 5 - GeoServer 2.2.x and earlier (Sun JRE tested)
> ```

There is then a [section on what you need to change if you want to run Java 17](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html#running-on-java-17):

> ### Running on Java 17
>
> GeoServer is compatible with Java 17, but requires extra care for
> running in some environments.
>
> Deployment on Tomcat 9.0.55 has been tested with success.
>
> The “bin” packaging can work too, but requires turning off the Marlin
> rasterizer integration. This can be done by modifying the scripts, or
> by simply removing the Marlin jars:
>
> rm webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/marlin-0.9.3.jar
>
> GeoServer code depends on a variety of libraries trying to access the
> JDK internals. As reported above, it does not seem to matter when
> running as a web application. However, in case of need, here is the
> full list of opens used by the build process:
>
> --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: I figured I'd stick to Java 11 but I'm right back where I started, everything's broken (I can open the site with SSL and log in but nothing else works properly. My SSL's probably messed up, no idea how to set it up right. I just used Certbot. I followed https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-setup-tomcat-with-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-on-ubuntu-18-04/ from step 9. I get a 400 when I try to save the proxy base URL config.

Comment: If you install GeoServer without SSL, is everything still broken?

Comment: I normally add SSL to a web server in front of GeoServer/Tomcat